# How could i reverse the letter order of a notepad text?

Tags: c#, string, console-application

I am reading a notepad text and inserting line per line in sLinge. I want to be able to invert the letters (for example: "Hi how are you" --> "uoy era woh iH")

i keep getting this error code:
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

this is the notepad content :

Anders Hejlsberg, né en décembre 1960, est un programmeur danois.
En 1980, il a commencé à écrire des programmes
pour le micro-ordinateur Nascom durant sa scolarité à l'Université
technique du Danemark d'où il sortit non diplômé; il a en particulier écrit
un compilateur Pascal qui a été vendu sous le nom de
Blue Label Pascal compiler pour le Nascom-2. Il l'a rapidement
réécrit pour CP/M et MS-DOS, et distribué sous le nom de Compass Pascal
puis de Poly Pascal. Après avoir été acquis par Borland,
il a été distribué sous le nom Turbo Pascal.

Le rachat par Borland de son logiciel a amené Hejlsberg à être
un des fondateurs de la société Borland dans laquelle il est
resté jusqu'en 1996. Il a continué
le développement du Turbo Pascal et est devenu chef de
projet lors de l'élaboration du langage Delphi,
successeur du Turbo Pascal.

En 1996, il a quitté Borland pour rejoindre Microsoft où il a
travaillé sur le langage J++ et les Windows Foundation Classes.
Il est le concepteur du Framework .NET.

Il travaille aujourd'hui chez Microsoft comme un chef de projet
et architecte logiciel du projet C#, ainsi que du projet TypeScript

Source: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anders_Hejlsberg

```
                        while (!fichier.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            sLigne = fichier.ReadLine();
                            iIndex = sLigne.Length;
                            while (iIndex >= sLigne.Length)
                            {
                                cChar = sLigne[iIndex];
                                sInverse += cChar;
                                iIndex--;
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine(sInverse);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(PAUSE);
                        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: [reverse-string-without-inbuilt-function-and-using-inbuilt-function](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/reverse-string-without-inbuilt-function-and-using-inbuilt-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can with a help of *Linq*: to *reverse* enumeration of `char` (which is the initial string) all you should do is to perform `Reverse()`. The you can obtain `string` from enumeration via `string.Concat`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

while (!fichier.EndOfStream)
{
    sLigne = fichier.ReadLine();
    sInverse = string.Concat(sLigne.Reverse());

    Console.WriteLine(sInverse);
}
```

Comment: This accomplishes your original goal, but you need to pay close attention to the other answer (and the one linked above) so you don't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

An array of length n goes from 0 to n-1, so the accessing `sLigne[iIndex]` will be out of bound. Do

```
cChar = sLigne[iIndex - 1]
```

instead
also the while condition idea is also incorrect, the code inside while-loop will only run once and quits. You can also do a normal for-loop.

```
    for (int i = sLigne.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sInverse += sLigne[i];
    }
```